# Authorization of Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a RESTful WebApi using Visual studio 2013 mvc, webapi2 and Odata,

which could be accessed from a mobile client.

I am following the tuitorial given below

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Now I am facing a some difficulty in authorization. I want the api secured and want to check whether the request in from proper user or not.

following is my client side code

```
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#post").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost:21900/odata/Products(1)",
                success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" id="post" value="Post"/>
</body>
```

and server side code

```
public class ProductsController : ODataController
{
    private ProductServiceContext db = new ProductServiceContext();


    [Queryable]
    public SingleResult<Product> GetProduct([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return SingleResult.Create(db.Products.Where(product => product.ID == key));
    }
}
```

I've tried the above with [Authorize] but is not working properly for me

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: How is `[Authorize]` not working for you?

Answer (score 4):

You have to create new attribute like following :-

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class AuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {       
        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);            

            ////check authentication and return if not authorized
            if (actionContext != null)
            {
                if (!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) { RequestMessage = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request };
                     return;
                }             

            }
        }
    }
```

after creating above filter attribute you can add it in webapiconfig.cs file like following so it will filter all your request.

```
config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

you can also add it for perticular methods or class like following

```
[AuthorizeAttribute]
public class TestController : ApiController
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods of securing your Web Api application. Basic authentication, OAuth, HMAC, API Keys, Custom tokens. A good starter can be found [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api) which also provides a sample app for download.

Answer (score 0):

I also work on a web api that users via mobiles can connect to it.
For `Authentication` i use `RSA` in .net. Clients in mobiles, first send a username and password, and i create a token and send it to client. In next requests client must append this token to request headers, and i get this token and extract username and password from it.

RSA encryption:

```
public class ApiRSA
    {
        private static string privateKey = // Generate a private key

        private static string publicKey = // Generate a public key

        public static string Decrypt(string data)
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] dataByte = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

            rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
            var decryptedByte = rsa.Decrypt(dataByte, false);

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedByte);
        }

        public static string Encrypt(string data)
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();

            var dataByte = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

            rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
            var encryptedByte = rsa.Encrypt(dataByte, false);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedByte);
        }

        public static void GeneraterPrivatePublicKey(out string privateKey, out string publicKey)
        {
            var csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);

            var privKey = csp.ExportParameters(true);
            var pubKey = csp.ExportParameters(false);

            {
                var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                xs.Serialize(sw, privKey);
                privateKey = sw.ToString();
            }

            {
                var sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                var xs = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
                xs.Serialize(sw, pubKey);
                publicKey = sw.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

This class will encrypt username and password into a string(token). In login method you check username and password and generate a token based on username and password and return this token.
In any further request, client must append this token in request header.

For checking further requests, you can use a custom authentication attribute:

```
public interface IApiAuthenticationProvider
    {
        bool IsValid(string username, string password);
    }

public static class ApiAuthenticationEncrypter
{
    public static string Encrypt(string username, string password)
    {
        return ApiRSA.Encrypt(/*join username and password*/);
    }

    public static void Decrypt(string token, out string username, out string password)
    {
        var usernameAndPass = ApiRSA.Decrypt(token).Split(/*split username and password*/);
        username = usernameAndPass[0];
        password = usernameAndPass[1];
    }
}

public class ApiAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        private IApiAuthenticationProvider AuthenticationProvider { get; set; }

        public ApiAuthenticationAttribute(Type apiAuthenticationType)
        {
            Debug.Assert(typeof(IApiAuthenticationProvider).IsAssignableFrom(apiAuthenticationType));
            AuthenticationProvider = (IApiAuthenticationProvider) Activator.CreateInstance(apiAuthenticationType);
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            Debug.Assert(AuthenticationProvider != null);

            Object httpContextBase;
            bool isValid = actionContext.Request.Properties.TryGetValue("MS_HttpContext", out httpContextBase);
            bool isLocal = isValid && ((HttpContextBase)httpContextBase).Request.IsLocal;

            if (isLocal)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
                return;
            }


            //// == Only Https request ==
            //if (!String.Equals(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme, "https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            //{
            //    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            //    {
            //        Content = new StringContent("HTTPS Required")
            //    };
            //    return;
            //}

            // == Try to get Token ==
            string token;
            try
            {
                token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("AuthenticationToken").First();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("AuthenticationToken not found"),
                };
                return;
            }

            // == Validate using validator provider ==
            try
            {
                string username;
                string password;
                ApiAuthenticationEncrypter.Decrypt(token, out username, out password);

                if (AuthenticationProvider.IsValid(username, password))
                    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
                else
                    throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Invalid UserName or Password")
                };
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

And use this attribute by a concrete type of `IApiAuthenticationProvider`:

```
[ApiAuthentication(typeof (Concrete Type of IApiAuthenticationProvider))]
public class SomeController: ApiController
```

Read [Here](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/)